# How to convert datetime to mmm-yy format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe where there is a column with datetime.

`2020-12-02 13:14:19`

How can I covert it in `mmm-yy` format. To get output like `Dec-20`.

Comment: December 1920? That's not a joke. Lloyd's and RBS systems crashed last year because their hacky Y2K fixes treated `20` as 1920. If there's *any* chance that the output of your program will be used by another program, don't use 2-digit years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `POSIXct` (if it is not already) and then use `format`

```
x <- '2020-12-02 13:14:19'
format(as.POSIXct(x), '%b-%y')
#[1] "Dec-20"
```